# Fedora installation on particular partition

Tags: fedora, partition, system-installation

Let's say in my disk I have two partition, Partition A 100Gb and Partition B 800Gb, I want to install fedora on partition A only. I don't want to touch partition B. Is it possible?

Comment: Yes. Did you try it? Installation process will guide you nicely through the selection of partition you want to use for Fedora.

Comment: Indeed I tried it, It was pretty much different with windows and yeah I am bit naive with unix architecture it was asking for creating root, home mount point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you check the docs? They're actually pretty detailed here — see particularly [5.4.10. Manual Partitioning](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/23/html/Installation_Guide/sect-installation-gui-manual-partitioning.html). You may also find the whole of [Appendix B: An Introduction to Disk Partitions](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/23/html/Installation_Guide/appe-disk-partitions-overview.html) to be helpful.

In this particular case, though I think the best way to go is to use automatic partitioning with the Reclaim Space option, as described [here](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/23/html/Installation_Guide/sect-installation-gui-storage-partitioning.html). Start with Automatic Partitioning, and then it will tell you there isn't space available. Choose Reclaim, and then *remove* the Partition A.

Automatic partitioning will then create a new partitioning scheme using that space, and will leave your current Partition B alone.

Depending on what you're doing with Partition B, you may also want to read the [Multiboot Guide](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/23/html/Multiboot_Guide/index.html).

Of course, *do* make sure you have backups available before trying anything like this. There's always the possibility of bugs (or human error). And, of course, a good backup is important anyway!